# How to install Passenger when using RVM?

Tags: ruby, rake, rvm, passenger

I'm using [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) and would like to install [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) on Snow Leopard. After installing the Passenger gem (version 2.2.15) I try run the Apache module installer script `passenger-install-apache2-module`. But it compains that it can't find rake:

> ...
>   * RubyGems... found
>   * Rake... **not found**
>   * rack... found
>   ...

There is already [a bug-report](https://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=504) for this on the passenger forum, but besides telling me to wait for Passenger 3, there doesn't seem to be any solution (symlinking /usr/bin/rake doesn't do the trick for me)

**Does anybody know of a way to hack around this just to get the Apache module installed?** Once installed I imagine it doesn't matter if the script can find rake or not.

Just some specs on my env:

> $ which ruby
>   /Users/watson/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/ruby
>
> $ ruby -v
>   ruby 1.8.7 (2010-04-19 patchlevel 253) [i686-darwin10.4.0], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2010.02
>
> $ which rake
>   /Users/watson/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@global/bin/rake
>
> $ rake -V
>   rake, version 0.8.7
>
> $ echo $PATH
>   /Users/watson/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@rails235/bin:/Users/watson/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@global/bin:/Users/watson/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/bin:/Users/watson/.rvm/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin

Comment: Passenger 3 beta is actually available as of last week, I believe, so no waiting involved. `gem install passenger --pre`

Comment: have you tried to folow the manual: http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/passenger/

Comment: Running Passenger 3 would be nice, but I'm not sure it's a good idea to run it in produktion yet. Yes I've followed the manual, using `rvm ree --passenger`. I've even tried to run the script with the rvm Ruby explicit like so: `passenger_ruby /Users/watson/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@rails235/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module`

Comment: I'd be useful to check the result of this command: "gem list"

Answer (score 2):

I was able to overcome this by using "passenger-install-apache2-module" rather than "sudo passenger-install-apache2-module"
Here's some background info- 
http://groups.google.com/group/phusion-passenger/browse_thread/thread/a7de8a0a3e4bac21?pli=1